# helm - check if the string is valid base64 enc or not

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jsonschema

I have a values.yaml and schema.json file. How can I validate in helm if the given string in values.yaml is valid base64 enc? Is it possible with schema.json?

```
description: "checking helm"
verify: false
Cert: "sdfdsfsakdlsnvmkl...."
```

Comment: Can you please add your values.yaml and schema.json file that you are currently using.

Comment: You could write a regexp for it if you really needed to, or try to `b64dec` it.  IME most Helm charts don't do extensive checking like this (but also give somewhat obscure errors when things go wrong).